# Grails: update view on data change

Tags: grails

What I would like to do is to update a .gsp page on data is change.

Something like this: 
http://weichhold.com/2009/07/20/updating-multiple-page-fragments-with-grails-and-ajax/ but here the content page doesn't change on data changes.

There is a easy way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The usually approach to updating the UI without a complete page refresh is through [Grails AJAX](http://www.grails.org/Ajax) calls.

However based on the limited information you have provided, I think you would need to implement some sort of polling mechanism to periodically call you server to determine if there is new data to render.

[Here is a jQuery Plugin to do what I have suggested](http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/posts/jquery-periodicalupdater-ajax-polling/)

Here is a [stackoverflow question](http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/posts/jquery-periodicalupdater-ajax-polling/) where a similar solution is coded directly in javascript